# Codename one GPS provider and current location

Tags: java, ios, gps, location, codenameone

I am working on an iOS app with [codename one](https://www.codenameone.com). I want to get the current location and send it by SMS.

I got this code from Java Android Studio, I don't know how to get the current location and also check if GPS is turned on.

I tried below, but without success (I'm not sure how they start the GPS and get the location)

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean enabledGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (!enabledGPS) {
   //alert GPS is off
}
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
// default
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Provider: " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onLocationChanged(location);
} else {
    //do something
}
```

**The onLocationChanged method:**

```
try {
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
    smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com/?q=");
    smsBody.append(gpsLocation.getLatitude());
    smsBody.append(",");
    smsBody.append(gpsLocation.getLongitude());

    String phnum="xxxxx";
    String smsbod= smsBody.toString();


    Display.getInstance().sendSMS(phnum,smsbod);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Dialog.show("Error!", "Failed to start.  installed?", "OK", null);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start the GPS in codenameone, you can only check if it's turned on and display a message if it's not.

Try the code below:

```
//Check if location is turned on and your app is allowed to use it.
if (Display.getInstance().getLocationManager().isGPSDetectionSupported()) {
    if (Display.getInstance().getLocationManager().isGPSEnabled()) {
        InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
        final Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
        //Cancel after 20 seconds
        Location loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(20000);
        ipDlg.dispose();
        if (loc != null) {
            double lat = loc.getLatitude();
            double lng = loc.getLongitude();
            try {
                Display.getInstance().sendSMS("09123456789", "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng, false);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Dialog.show("Error!", "Failed to start.  installed?", "OK", null);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Dialog.show("GPS error", "Your location could not be found, please try going outside for a better GPS signal", "Ok", null);
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.show("GPS disabled", "AppName needs access to GPS. Please enable GPS", "Ok", null);
    }
} else {
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    final Dialog ipDlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    //Cancel after 20 seconds
    Location loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(20000);
    ipDlg.dispose();
    if (loc != null) {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lng = loc.getLongitude();
        try {
            Display.getInstance().sendSMS("09123456789", "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng, false);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Dialog.show("Error!", "Failed to start.  installed?", "OK", null);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.show("GPS error", "Your location could not be found, please try going outside for a better GPS signal", "Ok", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: At this time, i dont receive errors, but nothing happend. Not sms sent, and not dialog box warnings. I turned the GPS

Comment: On which device are you trying this? Try changing this `Display.getInstance().sendSMS("09123456789", "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng, false);` to this `Display.getInstance().sendSMS("09123456789", "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng, true);`

Comment: I am using a Samsung Xcover 2 (android) the app it should work on IOS, but I think i can test it on any device first

Comment: You can edit my answer if there was any changes you made for it to work.